# Why Such A Small Characters?

Tags: support

Using Firefox 9.0.1 and constantly view SuperUser like this (you can open image in tab or window to zoom-in):

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: I think this question would be fit for the main site, if it is not a duplicate. The zoom level can be changed for any site. :)

Answer (score 12):

You've zoomed out. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or select **View > Zoom > Reset** and it'll be fine.

[image: zoom > reset]

---

Zoomed out view

[image: Zoomed out view]

---

Zoom level reset

[image: Zoom level reset]

Comment: thanks for the alternative step, @iglvzx

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, there is a related preference in `about:config` for remembering page specific zoom levels. If you do not care for this feature, or frequently change the zoom level by accident, you can set the following to **false**:

```
browser.zoom.siteSpecific
```

Now when you go back to the page, the zoom level be reset to `100%`.